# Could not write JSON Spring boot when entity return null

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, java-17

I'm using spring boot 3.0.1 and java 17
When I call entityManager.getById(entityId);
there are two cases when there is already an entity it returns well.
but when the entity returned is null this exception is thrown

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Unable to find entity.Users with id 11]
```

and added this property to application.properties file

```
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
```

but no result.

please don't don't refer another answer because I'm checked most StackOverflow questions like this.

any advice will be good.

code snippet

```
 public Users getById(Long entityId) {
        Optional.ofNullable(entityId).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Failed to retrieve NULL entityId parameter"));
        return userRepository.getById(entityId);
    }
```

i call this method in the `restcontroller` layer

Comment: Can you provide a little more context for the code that is erroring?

Comment: @Eric George I updated my question please check again

Comment: I don't think we have quite enough for a diagnosis yet. Can you post the `Users` entity? And possibly the `restcontroller` code? If you can wrap the call to the `.getById` method you included in a try/catch, you might be able to log a more meaningful error.